# Windows batch: Extract strings between brackets

Tags: batch-file

I'm struggling with a BATCH file and hopefully someone can help me.

I want to parse the parameters that are passed to a .BAT Windows file. Basically, I will receive 2 groups of parameters that are inside brackets. The general syntax is:

```
BuildApplication.bat (params_for_application_1) (params_for_ application2)
```

So I can grab the parameters for application 1 and parameters for application 2 and execute both applications from the batch file, example:

```
MyApp1.exe params_for_application_1
MyApp2.exe params_for_application_2
```

This is a common call to the batch file:

```
BuildApplication.bat (-m 15000 -I "include/fasm" -DDEBUG="yes" "C:\my_projects\test project\test.asm") ("C:\my_projects\test project\test.obj" -i 400)
```

So I would like grab the 2 above group of parameters.

> ```
> params_for_application_1 = -m 15000 -I "include/fasm" -DDEBUG="yes" "C:\my_projects\test project\test.asm"
> params_for_application_2 = "C:\my_projects\test project\test.obj" -i 400
> ```

Comment: `(` and `)` aren't brackets.  They're parentheses.  Brackets are `[` and `]`.  The difference is not just semantic.  There can be different behavior between the two.  If you're wondering, `{` and `}` are braces.

Comment: for the `{}` i prefer French brackets (according wikipedia this is used too) :-D

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "arg_line=%*"


for /f "useback tokens=1,3 delims=()" %%a in ('!arg_line!') do (
   set "param1=%%a"
   set "param2=%%b"
)

echo %param1%
echo %param2%
```

?

Comment: Should be `tokens=1,3` I believe, and remove the space from the delims.  Also, you could just put `"%*"` into the `for /f` loop without needing to set `%arg_line%`.

Comment: @rojo - yes m but now I've tested it with the given arguments . Because of the quotes and brackets useback and delayed expansion will be needed too.

Comment: Know what?  `%*` expansion is already delayed.  No need to risk mangling exclamation marks.  And `usebackq` isn't needed.  Just `for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=()" %%a in ("%*") do (` etc.

Comment: Um... `%*` expansion is not delayed, @rojo, it is done even before special characters like `^`, `&`, `(`, `)`, etc., are recognised; provide an argument enclosed in `""` and containing `()`, and you will notice `for /F` fails; `usebackq` is not needed though; to solve the `!` issue, just move the `setlocal` down one line and insert `endlocal` as the first command in the `for /F` loop; to avoid trouble with an empty argument string (no arguments provided), use `(""!arg_line!"")` and then the `~` modifier; in addition, this also annuls the default `eol=;` option implicitly;

Comment: @aschipfl If I copy npocmaka's script, remove delayed expansion and replace his `for /f` line with my own, it outputs OP's desired output.  There's no problem with conflicting quotation marks.

Comment: @rojo, it works with the OP's command line arguments as stated, but it fails as soon as an argument is quoted which contains `()` on its own; the approach from [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524783/windows-batch-extract-strings-between-brackets/41525238#comment70306357_41525238) also fails though; the solution from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41543734) can handle that, although it is not perfect since it is parsing the command line string simply from left to right...

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following to extract the strings in between `(` and `)` of the entire command line argument string and store them into an array called `$ARRAY[]`:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Initialise variables here:
set ^"STRING=%*^"
set /A "IDX=0"

rem /* Loop through the entire command line argument string and store
rem    every part in between `(`/`)` into the array `$ARRAY[]`: */
:LOOP
rem // Terminate loop if no string is left:
if not defined STRING goto :NEXT
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Check if string contains `(`:
if "!STRING!"=="!STRING:*(=!" (
    endlocal
    rem // No more `(` found, so terminate loop:
    goto :NEXT
)else (
    endlocal
    rem // `(` found, so increment index:
    set /A "IDX+=1"
)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Extract part between first `(` and first following `)`:
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=) eol=)" %%K in (" !STRING:*(=!") do (
    endlocal
    rem /* Store extracted part with a preceding SPACE into array variable;
    rem    this SPACE makes empty strings between `(`/`)` not to be lost: */
    set "$ARRAY[%IDX%]=%%K"
    rem // Store the remaining string behind `)`:
    set "STRING=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
)
endlocal
rem // Jump back to beginning of loop:
goto :LOOP

:NEXT
rem // Simply return the array, including the preceding SPACE:
2> nul set $ARRAY[

endlocal
exit /B
```